# How To Update row in custom wordpress table

Tags: database, wordpress

Ive  Tried And Tried Looking Up How To Approach Editing/Updating Rows In Custom Wordpress Tables I Have It Set To Grab Current logged in user's username  which then compares to a custom wp_ table With UserNAme As The Primary Key Which Then I Would Like To Edit A Particular Column/Field On That Particular Row By Passing The Value Of A Variable Over After It Confirms Current Logged In User Matches The Primary Key UserName In My Custom Table"wp_customers"  What Am I Doing Wrong With This Line Of Code Or Do You Have A Better Solution

```
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

$johnny = $current_user->user_login;
$subs = 'illinois';
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query(
    "
    UPDATE $wpdb->wp_Customers 
    SET BuyersAddress = $subs
    WHERE UserName = $johnny

    ");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this code.

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    $johnny = $current_user->user_login;
    $subs = 'illinois';
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name  = $wpdb->prefix."Customers";

    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $table_name 
                SET BuyersAddress = %s 
             WHERE UserName = %s",$subs, $johnny)
    );
```

Comment: Your code throws Missing argument 2 for wpdb::prepare(), .... I know its got to be something simple even in my code.. moreless i know im close and on the Right track. Its just like .. What Is It

Comment: I just want to say thank you very much ive been chisling and picking at forms for the past 2 days.. just trying different approaches but new i was close to what needed done just wasnt sure on the final approach. But its true character and effort that people bring forth to help one another like you done instead of being cyber bulys like ive seen in some of these posts.... Ill Be glad to pass the helping someday in coding if i get Over skilled in it.... once again thank you i really appreciate it IT WORKED

Comment: @CharlesHouserJunior, Glad to help you. Please accept the answer.

Comment: Absolutely amazing post. Thank you! :-D

Answer (score 8):

Try this code

A simple WordPress Update query

[WP Update](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#UPDATE_rows)

```
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();

$johnny = array('UserName' => $current_user->user_login);
$subs = array('BuyersAddress' => 'illinois');
global $wpdb;
$table_name  = $wpdb->prefix."Customers";

$wpdb->update($table_name, $subs, $johnny);
```

Hope this will help you

Answer (score 0):

```
$msg='';
                if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['submit']=='Submit')

{
                 $assID =12; //pass your table id
                 $table_name  = $wpdb->prefix."assigned_user"; //custom table name
                    $ds = $_POST['driverStatus'];
    $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $table_name SET driverStatus = '".$ds."' WHERE id ='".$assID."' ")
    );
    
    $msg = 'Successfully Delivered!';
}
```